# Compact Books and Papers on Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I'm trying to get a better perspective on the connections between both fields of analysis and other branches of mathematics and need to shore up on my core analysis. Rather than work my way through tomes like Stein's Real Methods or Yoshida's Functional Analysis right off the bat, I'd like to read some very compact (~100 pages) books on fundamental topics in analysis. (I am absolutely not avoiding these texts long term, my course texts for next year are precisely many of these tomes).

For background, I have a strong undergraduate education in mathematics, plus measure theory and wavelets but minus complex analysis. I am finishing up my undergrad degree next year and am ready to start specializing in analysis and optimization.

For harmonic analysis I've heard wonderful things about Wolff's notes so I will read those (and some of Muscalu-Schlag)

In particular I'm looking at texts for: complex analysis, spectral theory, PDEs (introductory), operator theory, abstract harmonic analysis, calculus of variations, geometric measure theory, and potential theory.

If anyone has recommendations for analysis papers, or short books/papers that are tangentially related to analysis (Wells Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds comes to mind, if a bit long) I'd be grateful to hear about it.

Edit: I should've been more clear with my background, I have read the real part of Rudin's "Real and Complex", am familiar with the notion of Sobolev and Besov spaces (but not deeply), have dealt with representations of finite and Lie groups, am comfortable with homology theory, have done some analysis on manifolds including sheaf cohomology, have done some (up to stochastic processes) probability w/ measure theory, and can handle a Haar measure here and there. Think strong undergraduate at a top university

Comment: Have you checked out Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis?

Comment: "Baby Rudin" aka Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin is also very dense, compact, and relevant to the modern topics.

Comment: Stein and Shakarchi's "Real Analysis" is also a great introduction to measure theory and the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: *I'd like to read some very [compact](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2309166) (~100 pages) books on fundamental topics in analysis* --- Your forgot to say "pun not intended"!

Comment: Haha yes, the irony is not lost on me